# pgsql merge two json arrays

Tags: sql, postgresql, union-all

I have to select two type of result set from a table and merge them in single json array
like

```
select col1,col2,col3 from table 1 order by col3 where col1< 2
union all 
select col1,col2,col3 from table 1 order by col1 where colo = 3
```

Its saying syntax error I believe due to order by.

I need to return this in json array so I am trying like this

```
SELECT (    SELECT json_agg(row)
            FROM (
         select col1,col2,col3 from table 1 order by col3 where col1< 2 ) row)
UNION ALL
  SELECT (SELECT json_agg(row)
            FROM (
        select col1,col2,col3 from table 1 order by col1 where colo = 3
) row)
```

Its retiring two json arrays i.e. obvious, How can I make this in single array

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the aggregation after the UNION:

```
select json_agg(t)
from (
  (select col1,col2,col3 from table1 order by col3 where col1< 2)
  union all 
  (select col1,col2,col3 from table1 order by col1 where colo = 3)
) t
```

Comment: its throwing syntax error if we use order by there

Comment: @Md.ParvezAlam: then put the sub-queries between parentheses - but honestly the `order by` doesn't really make sense to be to begin with

Comment: It was just parentheses issue... shit how stupid I am,, thanks brother